# Apple Mach-O error. Every app has this 2 same errors

Tags: xcode, clang

All my apps are not compiling anymore, and then 2 Apple Mach-O errors appear.

this is what Xcode shows:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: posix_spawn failed: Exec format error
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve it, just download the packs that are on:
 Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads